# Table inside fancyvrb with continuous colorbox?

Tags: color, fancyvrb, colorbox

So I'm trying to insert a table (with an image) in the middle of a `\fancyvrb` of R code. The `\fancyvrb` has a `\colorbox` around it in gray. Is there a way to get all three parts (verbatim pt1, table, verbatim pt2) to be all in the same continuous `\colorbox`?

I'm willing to forgo the bit that limits the colorbox widths to only the end of the text, instead allowing it to extend to the right margin of the page. But then there's still the problem if no whitespace intbetween the 3 parts

I was thinking maybe I could put everything into `\minipage` with a gray background, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution? Especially since I plan to employ that style many times.

**Attempt 1**

```
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\colorlet{code}{gray!15!}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newenvironment{cverbatim}
 {\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
 {\endSaveVerbatim
  \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
  \colorbox{code}{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
  \endflushleft}

\begin{cverbatim}
    library("Tidyverse")
    library("Quandl")
    JPGDP <- Quandl("FRED/JPNRGDPQDSNAQ", type="raw")
    \end{cverbatim}
\begin{tabular}{ c  c }\raisebox{-.945\height}     
     {\includegraphics{r/2.2.1}} & This is text
    \end{tabular}
\begin{cverbatim}
    p1 <- ggplot(JPGDP, aes(x=DATE, y=VALUE)) +
        geom_line()
    p1
    \end{cverbatim}
```

[image]

**Attempt 2**

```
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\colorlet{code}{gray!15!}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newenvironment{cverbatim}
 {\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
 {\endSaveVerbatim
  \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
  \colorbox{code}{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
  \endflushleft}

\begin{cverbatim}
    library("Tidyverse")
    library("Quandl")
    JPGDP <- Quandl("FRED/JPNRGDPQDSNAQ", type="raw")
    \end{cverbatim}
\colorbox{\begin{tabular}{ c  c }\raisebox{-.945\height}     
     {\includegraphics{r/2.2.1}} & This is text
    \end{tabular}
\begin{cverbatim}
    p1 <- ggplot(JPGDP, aes(x=DATE, y=VALUE)) +
        geom_line()
    p1
    \end{cverbatim}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple `tcolorbox`.

Of course, you will use your image instead of `example-image-a`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray!40,colframe=lightgray]
\begin{verbatim}
library("Tidyverse")
library("Quandl")
JPGDP <- Quandl("FRED/JPNRGDPQDSNAQ", type="raw")
\end{verbatim}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xl@{}}   
     \includegraphics[align=t,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} & This is text
\end{tabularx}
\begin{verbatim}
p1 <- ggplot(JPGDP, aes(x=DATE, y=VALUE)) +
        geom_line()
p1
\end{verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]